# application.js:16 Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js)SyntaxError Unexpected token, expected "," (23:4)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code imported in my Ruby on Rails application. the importing seems to have been successful. However, I can't seem to get over this error that pops up in my console when I refresh the page. not to mention none of this code works. its supposed to add a border color to the post cards borders. but I keep getting this error. Where did I take a wrong turn?

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    if ($(".single-post-card").length) {
        // set a solid background color style
        if (mode == 1) {
            $(".single-post-card").each(function() {
                $(this).addClass("solid-color-mode");
                $(this).css('background-color', randomColor());
            });
        }
        // set a border color style
        else {
            $(".single-post-card").each(function() {
                $(this).addClass("border-color-mode");
                $(this).css('border', '5px solid ' + randomColor());
            });
        }   
    }


    $('#feed').on( 'mouseenter', '.single-post-list', function() {
        $(this).css('border-color', randomColor()); 
    });

    $('#feed').on( 'mouseleave', '.single-post-list', function() {
        $(this).css('border-color', 'rgba(0, 0 , 0, 0.05)');    
    });

});

var colorSet = randomColorSet();
var mode = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

// Randomly returns a color scheme
function randomColorSet() {
    var colorSet1 = ['#45CCFF', '#49E83E', '#FFD432', '#E84B30', '#B243FF'];
    var colorSet2 = ['#FF6138', '#FFFF9D', '#BEEB9F', '#79BD8F', '#79BD8F'];
    var colorSet3 = ['#FCFFF5', '#D1DBBD', '#91AA9D', '#3E606F', '#193441'];
    var colorSet4 = ['#004358', '#1F8A70', '#BEDB39', '#FFE11A', '#FD7400'];
    var colorSet5 = ['#105B63', '#FFFAD5', '#FFD34E', '#DB9E36', '#BD4932'];
    var colorSet6 = ['#04BFBF', '#CAFCD8', '#F7E967', '#A9CF54', '#588F27'];
    var colorSet7 = ['#405952', '#9C9B7A', '#FFD393', '#FF974F', '#F54F29'];
    var randomSet = [colorSet1, colorSet2, colorSet3, colorSet4, colorSet5, colorSet6, colorSet7];
    return randomSet[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomSet.length )];
}

// Randomly returns a color from an array of colors
function randomColor() {
    var color = colorSet[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorSet.length)];
    return color;
}
```

Error:

```
application.js:16 Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/app/javascript/posts/style.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (23:4)

  21 |   $('#feed').on( 'mouseenter', '.single-post-list', function() {
  22 |     $(this).css('border-color', randomColor());
> 23 |   });
     |     ^
  24 |
  25 | $('#feed').on( 'mouseleave', '.single-post-list', function() {
  26 |   $(this).css('border-color', 'rgba(0, 0 , 0, 0.05)');
    at Parser._raise (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:776)
    at Parser.raiseWithData (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:769)
    at Parser.raise (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:737)
    at Parser.unexpected (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9735)
    at Parser.expect (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9721)
    at Parser.parseCallExpressionArguments (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10890)
    at Parser.parseCoverCallAndAsyncArrowHead (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10816)
    at Parser.parseSubscript (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10752)
    at Parser.parseSubscripts (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10725)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10714)
    at Parser.parseUpdate (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10688)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10666)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10523)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10497)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10460)
    at Parser.parseExpressionBase (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10405)
    at :3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10399
    at Parser.allowInAnd (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12098)
    at Parser.parseExpression (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10399)
    at Parser.parseStatementContent (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12390)
    at Parser.parseStatement (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12259)
    at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12845)
    at Parser.parseBlockBody (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12836)
    at Parser.parseProgram (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12190)
    at Parser.parseTopLevel (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12181)
    at Parser.parse (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:13892)
    at parse (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:13944)
    at parser (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/parser/index.js:54)
    at parser.next (<anonymous>)
    at normalizeFile (:3000/home/maryan/Desktop/workspace/collabfield/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/normalize-file.js:55)
    at Object../app/javascript/posts/style.js (application.js:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../app/javascript/packs/application.js (application.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
```

Any help is highly appreciated.